# Upload and save images to other project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following project structure.

Solution :

- Project 1
- Project 2

I implement upload function in controller of Project 1 and I want the images that are uploaded to be in images folder of Project 2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the files in a folder on the server disk and each project then accesses the files with a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx) for example

Comment: Thanks you so much!
But I want url of image is the same http://abcd.com/images/abcd.jpg.
If i follow your way, Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public ActionResult UploadPicture(Picture picture)
    {
        foreach (var file in picture.Files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }            
        return View();
    }
```

Picture code:

```
public class Picture
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @user3408888 please upvote and accept this answer if this answer helps you, so people know this is the correct answer.